# Masking a password without using any plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

User is giving password in Jenkins password parameter. I have to encrypt the password in run time to avoid plain text format in Jenkins console output.

I don't want to use mask password plugin and wrap(mask password) in pipeline script. Is there anyway to mask the password using Jenkins pipeline script i.e stopping the echo to the password parameter

Comment: I think the concept of a parameter and the concept of credentials just dont match.